# What situations would the Deagle be preferred?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In what situations would the Deagle be a preferred choice over the Tec9/Five Seven. The Tec 9 and Five Seven both have larger mags, are quite accurate while moving, and are cheaper; however, I find myself facing people using a Deagle quite often. Is the choice a preference or are there situations where the Deagle is a stronger choice in the round and is this dependent on what map is being played?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Economics and personal preferences aside, use it when your opponents will have armor (head armor specifically) and you are going to be fighting at distance or not rushing.

At long distances deagles are still 1 hit head shots, while other pistols are not.

If you are going to be fighting at close distances or while on the run (perhaps during a rush), then the others pistols are a better choice than a deagle.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the Deagle when it's an eco round and I have the most money in my team. Usually only on de_dust 2 or de_overpass and I'll hold long. It's difficult to use it close range.